# Not sure why this function returns a reversed array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a JavaScript exercise and having some trouble untangling the logic as to why it works. It basically has a function called "mystery" that uses a bunch of very simple functions, and returns an array you give it but in reversed order. I've been sitting in front of a whiteboard for an hour trying to figure out the logic behind it, and not getting it. Can a kind soul take a look at these functions and explain how the mystery function returns a reversed array? Thank you!

```
function rest(arr) {
  return arr.slice(1);
}


function first(arr) {
  return arr[0];
}

function conj(arr, value) {
  arr.push(value);
  return arr;
}

function mystery(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  return conj(mystery(rest(array)), first(array));
}
```

Comment: Try to actually run it, use the debugger to trace through it, line by line...

Answer (score 2):

mystery is a recursive function.

It calls itself using the return value of the `rest` function, which returns everything except the first element.

It uses the result of that + the result of `first`, which returns the first character, and concatenates them again (using `conj`), but with the first element at the end.

So, say you put in [H e l l o],

it will return `conj(mystery([e l l o], H)`

`mystery([e l l o])` will return `conj(mystery([l l o], e)`

`mystery([l l o])` will return `conj(mystery([l o], l)`

and so on, until the array that goes into `mistery` is empty, in which case the recursion ends, and we bubble back up to the first call.

Side note, recursion is often used for exercises like this, but although it has some specific uses, in many cases it's way more efficient to not use recursion, because the overhead of making another function call is relatively hard work, compared to other solutions using a simple loop to move or swap items around.

You can see what is happening if you output some information:

```js
function rest(arr) {
  return arr.slice(1);
}


function first(arr) {
  return arr[0];
}

function conj(arr, value) {
  arr.push(value);
  return arr;
}

function mystery(array, level) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    console.log('mystery level '+level+' is called with an empty array. Recursion ends here.. Stay tuned for the answer.');
    return [];
  }
  console.log('mystery level '+level+' is called with '+array+
              '. I will move '+first(array)+' to the end.');
  
  var result = conj(mystery(rest(array), level+1), first(array));
  console.log('returning '+result+' for level '+level);
  return result;
}

console.log(mystery(['H','e','l','l','o'], 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand a function that uses recursion it can help to just *assume* for a moment that the *recursive* (nested) call returns what it should and then see how it builds on that to produce a correct result.

Let's for example suppose that `array` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

So this line:

```
 conj(mystery(rest(array)), first(array));
```

... has a recursive call of `mystery`. It gets as argument the `array`, but with the first element removed from it (that is what `rest` returns), so it gets `[2, 3, 4]`

Now we will just assume that this recursive call of `mystery` does the right thing and reverses that array into `[4, 3, 2]`. Then in the above quoted code we see this result is concatenated with `first(array)` (which is the first value, i.e. 1). So we get `[4, 3, 2, 1]`. Correct!

This teaches us that if we assume `mystery` does the job right for an array with n-1 values, it also does it right for n values.

Now remains to see whether `mystery` deals correctly with the smallest case, i.e. when the array is empty. It is easy to see it returns the correct result in that case, i.e. an empty array.

So putting those two things together you can see that `mystery` does the job correctly for all possible array sizes.

Answer (score 1):

your first function "rest" removes the first element, as slice will return elements from 1 to the end of the array, then the "conj" function will take the first element that was removed (through the "first" function) and put it in the end, and doing so recursively it'll take elements from the beginning and put them to the end.

Answer (score 1):

The `.push` method places the item to end of array.
`.slice(1)` means “except the first item”

#### Pseudocode

1. Get array A (arg of `mystery`). If it is empty, return it
2. Take `rest` (everything except the first). We will call the rest B
3. Run this program on B (recursively)
4. Append the first item of A to end of B

---

`conj` = append `value` to `arr`

`first` = get first item of `arr`

`rest` = return everything except the first item

`mystery` when `array` is empty = return empty array

`mystery` when `array` is not empty = Take `rest(array)`, run `mystery` on it, then append `first` of array

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the magic of recursion. To understand think about what it does if you call `mystery` with a 2-element array `[1,2]`.

`rest(array)` will then be `[2]` `mystery(rest(array))` will also be `[2]`

`first(array)` will be `1`.

Then you return `conj([2], 1)` which locically results in `[2,1]`.

Now the trick is the recursion. If you have 3 elements `[0,1,2]` and call mystery with it this will happen:

- it will call `mystery(rest(array))` with essentially is `mystery([1,2])`. That this returns `[2,1]` have we already seen.
- `first(array)` will be `0`
- so it returns `conj([2,1],0)` which is logically `[2,1,0]`.

this now recusivly works for as many elements as you wish. Essentially `mystery` will be called for every element to place it after all elements.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note here is that `mystery()` is called recursively. I added some comments to illustrate what's going on on each step.

```js
function rest(arr) {
  console.log('take first n-1 elements of', arr);
  return arr.slice(1);
}


function first(arr) {
  return arr[0];
}

function conj(arr, value) {
  arr.push(value);
  console.log('combine', arr, 'with', value)
  return arr;
}

function mystery(array) {
  console.log('call mystery on ', array)
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  return conj(mystery(rest(array)), first(array));
}

mystery([0,1,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. The reason for you not being able to see it is **RECURSION**. Couple things, that I would like you to notice:

- mystery(array) is recursive function because it call itself until the array passed in is emplty
- all of your work is happening here: ***return conj(mystery(rest(array)), first(array));***

I'm not going to talk more about recursive function here rather I will show how you can track each recursive call using **console.log()**. Check out my code below, I've added console.log() to make things more clear for you. Try running mystery with some array and see results. This will make sense to you.

```js
function rest(arr) {
  return arr.slice(1);
}


function first(arr) {
  console.log("Returning ",arr[0], "from first(arr).")
  return arr[0];
}

function conj(arr, value) {
  console.log("Pushing ",value, " to ",arr, " in conj(arr,value)");
  arr.push(value);
  console.log("Returning ",arr, " from Conj(arr,value)");
  return arr;
}

function mystery(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    console.log("array is emplty. So, returning empty array from mystery");
    return [];
  }
  console.log("array is not emplty. So, calling mystery(array) again.");
  return conj(mystery(rest(array)), first(array));
}
var reverse =mystery([1,2,3,4]);
console.log("The final result", reverse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not gonna lie, this is a weird way to reverse the order of the array. It's basically using recursion to slice the first element of the array and conjoin the elements with first element at the end.

So here's a walk though:

`mystery(['h','e','l','l','o'])` ->

first check if array is empty then method `rest` is called ->

`rest(['h','e','l','l','o'])` ->

rest slices the array at index 1 returning a new array of `['e','l','l','o']` ->

then `mystery` is called which repeats the previous steps with the return value of `rest` ->

`mystery(['e','l','l','o'])` ->

this means the mystery will be keep getting called on until `rest` returns an empty array ->

`mystery(['e','l','l','o'])` ->
`mystery(['l','l','o'])` ->
`mystery(['l','o'])` ->
`mystery(['o'])` ->
`mystery([])` ->

when mystery has an empty array it returns the empty array and then `first` is called ->
first returns just the first element of the array and happens after mystery is returned it would look something like this before mystery is returned ->

`mystery(['e','l','l','o']) , first(['h','e','l','l','o'])` ->
so at the lowest level when mystery returns an empty array and first return the first element in `['o']` it would look like this ->

`[] , ['o']` ->
`conj` would be called with these values ->
`conj([] , ['o'])` ->
`conj` returns the combination of the two values ->
`conj([] , ['o'])` ->
`['o']` ->
this is then returned and repeated ->
`conj([] , ['o'])` ->
`conj(['o'] , ['l'])` ->
`conj(['o','l'] , ['l'])` ->
`conj(['o', 'l','l'] , ['e'])` ->
`conj(['o', 'l','l', 'e'] , ['h'])` ->
`['o', 'l','l', 'e','h']`